Why are my messages not getting from SNS Subscription to Firehose Endpoint?
I am looking to log sent emails from Amazon SES to an S3 bucket. To do this I am trying to leverage Amazon SNS to push data through a Firehose Stream and into the S3 bucket.
The problem that I am having is that I am unable to get data from the SNS Subscription to my Firehose Stream.
To do this I have created an Amazon SNS Topic, a Subscription from the topic to the Firehose Stream, the Firehose stream itself an S3 bucket and an IAM Role.
I can test data moving from the Firehose Stream into the bucket in the Firehose AWS portal and that is fine, so I don't believe there is an issue there. I have also tried a second subscription to the topic that sends me an email and this is fine when I publish data to the Topic, but the same data never reaches the Firehose Stream from looking at the AWS portal analytics and therefore never appears in the S3 bucket.
Is there any way for me to debug this?
I am using the following details in the IAM Role for the SNS Subscription, which from reading the documentation seems to be correct and more than everything I need.
Permissions for IAM Role
Trust relationship for IAM Role
Any help would be much appreciated.
